# Using intent to start WhatsApp with just an URL

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I'm using intents to link to several social media apps in a native android app. This looks like the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://whatsapp.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID"));
this.requireActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

This code works perfectly fine with Facebook, Instagram and TikTok. If the apps are installed it will open them, if not it will open a webbrowser.

But with WhatsApp nothing happens. My Fragment is paused and immideatly resumed and that's it.
If I use the PackageManager and use "com.whatsapp" it works perfectly fine, but I would like to not do this because those links are dynamically loaded and I would like to not implement a "WhatsApp exception".

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Could you please update your code snippet with the WhatsApp URL? Because currently there's a facebook URL.

Comment: Are you sure you use the correct deeplink for WhatsApp?

Comment: `Do you have any idea why this might be happening?` Well you might better wonder yourself, and then tell us, why with those other apps those apps are launched instead of a browser with the requested page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The problem was that I had WhatsApp installed, but not configured (not registered a Phone Number yet). So the intent did start whatsapp, but the app somehow couldn't handle the call and it seemed like nothing was happening.